# How to use css-to-react-native

Tags: react-native

Dumb question. I've added `css-to-react-native` to my project, but the Readme doesn't actually give instructions on how to use it – well of course there are instructions on how to *use* its functionality but not how to tell my project to use it. Do I `import` it, or part of it, into the file where I want to use it? Some other kind of set up?

Comment: did you check there https://github.com/styled-components/css-to-react-native#api

Comment: It looks like `transform` is meant to be used when programming an API on top of theirs, not to be used in normal RN development. The implementation for normal RN development should look something like `border: 10 20 red` but I don't know how to allow that implementation.